# Error while compiling a simple project

Tags: compiler-errors, wxwidgets, codeblocks, undefined-reference, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile a project in CodeBlocks (12.11) with wxWidgets 64 bit (2.8.12) and I am getting this errors:

```
undefined reference to `__imp_z22wxInitAllImageHandlersv'|
undefined reference to `__imp_ZN12wxAppConsole17CheckBuildOptionsEPKcS1_'|
undefined reference to `__imp_ZN5wxAppC2Ev'|
undefined reference to `__imp_ZN12wxAppConsole14ms_appInstanceE'|
undefined reference to `__imp_Z7wxEntryP11HINSTANCE__50_Pci'|
```

How can I resolve this troubles?

PS: wxWidgets library compiled correctly and CodeBlocks recognized it.

**EDIT**

```
-------------- Build: Release in amdwx (compiler: MinGW64)---------------

g++.exe -LC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll  -o bin\Release\amdwx.exe obj\Release\amdwxApp.o obj\Release\amdwxMain.o  obj\Release\resource.res  -s -mthreads  C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw28u.a  -mwindows
obj\Release\amdwxApp.o:amdwxApp.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `__imp__Z22wxInitAllImageHandlersv'
obj\Release\amdwxApp.o:amdwxApp.cpp:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12wxAppConsole17CheckBuildOptionsEPKcS1_'
obj\Release\amdwxApp.o:amdwxApp.cpp:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5wxAppC2Ev'
obj\Release\amdwxApp.o:amdwxApp.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12wxAppConsole14ms_appInstanceE'
obj\Release\amdwxApp.o:amdwxApp.cpp:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `__imp__Z7wxEntryP11HINSTANCE__S0_Pci'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: obj\Release\amdwxApp.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata$_ZN12wxEvtHandler12TryValidatorER7wxEvent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 7 seconds)
5 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 7 seconds)
```

I have the following files in my project:

pastebin.com/iDDbpUQ5 -> amdwxMain.h

pastebin.com/jk47hHVY -> amdwxMain.cpp

pastebin.com/KP9e5AzB -> amdwxApp.h

pastebin.com/x57pBLHZ -> amdwxApp.cpp

I posted in pastebin servers because it was too many files.

Comment: Can you give the complete BUILD LOG(Errors) by updating the question?Also put the some code which you implemented

Comment: I have just updated my question, Thank you